Restore Uri from SharedPreferencies - No persistable permission grants
How to backup/restore some Uri for reuse after app restart?
We have a Uri from a file picker and use it to save some data to the file. Now we want to backup this Uri (file path):
myPrefsEdit.putString("uriLogFile", selectedFileUri.toString());
myPrefsEdit.commit();

When the application is restarted, we want to restore the Uri (file path):
selectedFileUri = Uri.parse(myPrefsEdit.getString("uriLogFile", ""));

(And it´s functional...) Now we tried asking permission:
try {
    getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(selectedFileUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // handle failure to get persistable permission
    e.printStackTrace();
}

But an exception occured:
java.lang.SecurityException: No persistable permission grants found for UID 10330 and Uri content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/...
